# SQL - How to return multiple rows that have identical field in php

Tags: php, android, sql

I'm using this php script to access a remote database from an android app. I am trying to search for Games with a certain location to find all the games going on at that location. The problem is my php file is only returning me the most recently created game, is there a way I can go through and return all the games one by one if there are 2 games with the same value for 'location'?

```
<?php
/*server, user, password, databse */
$conn=mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x","x");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$location = $_POST["location"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM Games WHERE location = ?");
if($statement === FALSE){ die(mysqli_error($conn)); }

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $location);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
//printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($statement));

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $user, $time, $date, $num_players, $location);

    $game = array ();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $game[user] = $user;
        $game[time] = $time;
        $game[date] = $date;
        $game[num_players] = $num_players;
        $game[location] = $location;
    }

    echo json_encode($game);


mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

?>

Comment: What's your data structure?

Comment: I have a table called Games, and in that table it stores all of the games that have been created through the app. There can be multiple games at the same location and when I use this php code it is only returning me the most recently created game with whatever location is specified.

Comment: Can you run that query ("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE location = ?") in mysql console. What is the result?

Comment: the select statement I'm essentially running is SELECT * FROM Games WHERE location = "Lady Bug Park"; and when I run that in the console it returns all 4 games with location = lady bug park

Comment: @BryanPenaloza , Check the documentation of "mysqli_stmt_fetch": http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php ; It says that this function will return **false on errors** and **null on end**. Check the return value of "mysqli_stmt_fetch".